# Android Intent for Image received in Whatsapp

Tags: android

First of all: I am no Android Developer and need some help for a technical feasbility for an app.

I would like to get notified when a picture has been received e.g. in Whatsapp. I've already found out that it is generally possible, when the image is made with the camera and saved inside the media store. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE).

At least on Whatsapp for iOS I can disable the feature, that sent and received photos will automatically be transferred to the media store (on iOS it is called Image Library). And if deactivating that is possible on Android, too, I need to

1. get notified when a new image has been received in Whatsapp itself.
2. and I should also be able to access that photo, event when it is stored in Whatsapp's directory.

Is that possible? Or only when an image is saved into the media store?

Comment: "I've already found out that it is generally possible, when the image is made with the camera and saved inside the media store" -- there is no requirement that any camera app send this broadcast, let alone non-camera apps. Few images will be reported via this broadcast. "Is that possible?" -- hopefully not, for obvious privacy and security reasons.